# matInput binded to context property conflicts with i18n extraction but not on regular serve

Tags: angular, internationalization, directive, angular-i18n, angular-input

I have that piece of code of a reactive form that compiles right and is well executed with the `matInput` directive which is binded, but when I run the angular cli command for internationalisation (`ng xi18n`), then I got the following error `ERROR in Can't bind to 'matInput' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.` I don't understand that error on i18n extract but not on regular execution. When I remove the bind on the matInput it works well on both exec and i18n extract.

Here is why I use `matInput` binded (so as `[matInput]`): in my ts file, I defined a context per form-field that tells if it needs a directive or not (`matInput` and `required`) and that gives the value of the directives that need one (`formControlName`, `type` and `placeHolder`):

```
public myForm: FormGroup
public emailContext: any
public nameContext: any
public passwordContext: any

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){

  // Form creation
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    email: [""],
    name: [""],
    password: [""],
  })

  // Each input field will receive it's own context as a simple object:
  public emailContext = {
    controls: {
      formControlName: email, // value to give to the regular [formControlName]
      matInput: true, // true or false if we want apply or not matInput to the input
      required: true, // true or false if we want apply or not the required to the input
      type: "text", // value we want to pass to the regular [type] directive
      placeHolder: $localize`:"@@email:Email"`, // value to pass to the place holder
    }
  }
  public nameContext = {
    controls: {
      formControlName: name,
      matInput: true,
      required: false,
      type: "text",
      placeHolder: $localize`:"@@name:Name"`,
    }
  }
  public passwordContext = {
    controls: {
      formControlName: password,
      matInput: true,
      required: false,
      type: "password",
      placeHolder: $localize`:"@@city:City"`,
    }
  }
```

That allows me in the html file to write only one `ng-template` that I will call in a `ng-container` with the `ngTemplateOutlet` directive for each input, in which I give the concerned context object with all the needed info about directives for a given form field

```
<!-- Describes the input template with all binded directives to ts context object-->
<ng-template #inputTemplate let-ctrl="controls">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input [formControlName]="ctrl.formControlName" 
         [matInput]="ctrl.matInput" 
         [required]="ctrl.required" 
         [type]="ctrl.type"
         [placeholder]="ctrl.placeHolder">
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inputTemplate ; context: emailCtx"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inputTemplate ; context: nameCtx"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inputTemplate ; context: passwordCtx"></ng-container>
```

Even if I had never seen matInput binded, I found it was elegant to describe a form field in the ts file with the context objects, and then simplify the html file with only one ng-template instead of repeated mat-form-fields.
BUT, even if this works well when on regular execution with `ng serve` then I have an error when I run the `ng xi18n` (used to edit the xlf files with the placeHolders to translate from ts file).

1. Is this "allowed" to bind matInput this way, I mean in the same way
   we apply or not classes with the `[class.my-class]="<boolean>"`?
2. Even if this works, I don't understand how the binding makes the
   difference between `[required]="true"` which means "apply required
   directive" and `[type]="text"` which means "give the "text" value to
   the type directive". And so, with the context described in the ts file, how could I pass a boolean to a driective, not just telling it to be applied or not like in the `[class.my-class]="<boolean>"`
3. How could the binded [matInput] couldn't be a problem on regular
   serve and cause crash on i18n extraction?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 11 I get the error on property binding of [matInput] even on serve and build. Besides you cannot use mat-form-field element with input without matInput directive.